# After add additional Boolean Column, hibernate merge not working with created Object

Tags: hibernate, session, spring-mvc, orm, annotations

```
@Field(analyze = Analyze.NO)
private boolean usernameChange;

@Column
public boolean getusernameChange() {
    return usernameChange;
}
public void setusernameChange(boolean usernameChange) {
    this.usernameChange =usernameChange ;
}
```

Hi, I just modified previous entity with additional Boolean Column. I can get all values from user side to server side. But, merge the object using session.merge(), it does not update the Boolean value into the database. Please any one help me to solve this issue. I wasted more time to solve this issue but i still face the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set default value for boolean. NULL value is not permitted, you should add a column like this in the database :

```
ALTER TABLE table_name add column column_name boolean default false/true;
```

Then you wont have merge issues. Please also name the column.